# How to dynamic replace code when a external js file loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When dynamic loading an external js file, I want to replace some html content in the js file. How can I do that?

Example:

The code in a js file as below:

```
<img src="path1">
```

I want to change the src path of the img tag. I once use jquery to do that, but before the js file loaded, can not find the img tag.

Comment: @IvoVidovicWell, i dont see any snippet of javascript here, either...

Comment: How are you loading the js file? If you create a `<script>`, append it to your `document.body`, then set its `src` to the URL of the script, it will get executed as usual, and can alter the document as usual.

Comment: Hi, thanks,the external js file was loaded dynamically, not with <script> tag, it was loaded via another js file, so , the jquery can not find the DOM due to the external js file not loaded, i mean, should i listen to the external js file, but how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can change the `src` of an image right after the DOM is loaded. With Jquery there're many ways to do it. Try one of the following:

```
$(function(){
  //execute whatever you want with the DOM loaded
});


$(document).ready(function(){
  // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
});


$( window ).load(function() {
  // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
});
```

In all of these solutions you will have access to the element that you need, in this case the `img` element.

Comment: Hi, thanks, i suer did it before, but the external js file was loaded dynamically, not with <script> tag, it was loaded via another js file, so , the jquery can not find the DOM due to the external js file not loaded, i mean, should i listen to the external js file, but how to do that?

Comment: Can you give a snippet example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sure, i want to add google translate plugin on my wordpress site, and my host in China, google translate plugin use </script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit2"></script>

Comment: Sure, i want to add google translate plugin on my wordpress site, and my host in China, google translate plugin use <script type =“text / javascript”src =“// translate.google.com/translate_a/ element.js？CB = googleTranslateElementInit2" > </ SCRIPT>, then load another js file called main_zh-CN.js, and main_zh-CN.js will load 3rd js file called element.main.js,

Comment: In the element.main.js file, it output an image cleardot.gif, which src is: https://www.google.com/images/cleardot.gif, i want to change it to https://www.google.cn, because we can not visite www.google.com, but google.cn will ok, pls forgive my poor englsh, hope you understand my mean.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do but, how are you loading another JS file inside a JS file?